# Changing line color in ggplot based on slope

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following code which plots points and draw a line between them.

```
ggplot (data = subset(df, vowel == "O" & gender == "f"), aes (x = time, y = val, color = formant)) +
      geom_point()+
      geom_line(aes(group=interaction(formant, number)))
```

It produces this:

[image]

Is there a way to group these by color/line type for negative slopes vs. positive slopes of these lines?

edit:
Here is my data:

```
number <- c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3)
formant <- c("F2", "F2", "F2", "F2", "F2", "F2", "F3", "F3", "F3", "F3", "F3", "F3")
time <- c(50, 50, 50, 99, 99, 99, 50, 50, 50, 99, 99, 99)
val <- c(400, 500, 600, 450, 550, 650, 300, 400, 500, 250, 350, 450)
```

I want to show movement of in the value of `val` over `time` grouped by `formant` and `number`. So when I implement the answer, it tells me I have an incompatible size, which I think has something to do with the fact that it's grouped by number.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You haven't provided sample data, so here's a stylized example. The general idea is that you create a variable that tests whether the slope is greater than zero and then map that to a colour aesthetic. In this case, I use the `dplyr` chaining operator (`%>%`) in order to add the slope on the fly within the call to `ggplot`. (I went to the trouble of calculating the slope, but you could just as well test whether `value[t==2] > value[t==1]` instead.)

```
library(dplyr)

# Fake data
set.seed(205)
dat = data.frame(t=rep(1:2, each=10), 
                 pairs=rep(1:10,2), 
                 value=rnorm(20), 
                 group=rep(c("A","B"), 10))

dat$value[dat$group=="A"] = dat$value[dat$group=="A"] + 6

ggplot(dat %>% group_by(pairs) %>%
         mutate(slope = (value[t==2] - value[t==1])/(2-1)),
       aes(t, value, group=pairs, linetype=group, colour=slope > 0)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

**UPDATE:** Based on your comment, it sounds like you just need to map `number` to an aesthetic or use faceting. Here's a facetted version using your sample data:

```
df = data.frame(number, formant, time, val)

# Shift val a bit
set.seed(1095)
df$val = df$val + rnorm(nrow(df), 0, 10)

ggplot (df %>% group_by(formant, number) %>%
          mutate(slope=(val[time==99] - val[time==50])/(99-50)), 
        aes (x = time, y = val, linetype = formant, colour=slope > 0)) +
  geom_point()+
  geom_line(aes(group=interaction(formant, number))) +
  facet_grid(. ~ number)
```

[image]

Here's another option that maps `number` to the size of the point markers. This doesn't look very good, but is just for illustration to show how to map variables to different "aesthetics" (colour, shape, size, etc.) in the graph.

```
ggplot (df %>% group_by(formant, number) %>% 
          mutate(slope=(val[time==99] - val[time==50])/(99-50)), 
        aes (x = time, y = val, linetype = formant, colour=slope > 0)) +
  geom_point(aes(size=number))+
  geom_line(aes(group=interaction(formant, number)))
```

Comment: Thank you! But, this doesn't end up working with my data, since it has to be grouped by an arbitrary number. Sorry I didn't post my data originally, I will write the code recreating it.

Comment: Is there a shorter way because if i make my database dynamic like with time-series, the 2 - 1 in the slope calculation part will become useless as it is too small(as it shall have many consecutive line)