# Changing line color in ggplot based on "several factors" slope

Tags: r, ggplot2

UPDATED: 
I have the following data which I would like to draw a line between the groups, based on the slope of 3 factors `("I","II","III").

```
set.seed(205)
dat = data.frame(t=rep(c("I","II","III"), each=10), 
             pairs=rep(1:10,3), 
             value=rnorm(30), 
             group=rep(c("A","B"), 15))
```

I have tried the following, but I cannot manage to connect change the color of the line connecting "I" - "III" and "II" - "III":

```
ggplot(dat %>% group_by(pairs) %>%
     mutate(slope = (value[t=="II"] - value[t=="I"])/( value[t=="II"])- value[t=="I"]),
   aes(t, value, group=pairs, linetype=group, colour=slope > 0)) +
geom_point() +
geom_line()
```

This is a very similar issue to 
[Changing line color in ggplot based on slope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34113989/changing-line-color-in-ggplot-based-on-slope)

I hope I was able to explain my problem.

Comment: The desired output is unclear. Please post an example of what you are looking for in the end. Also, we do not have object `GM` defined, we cannot see the error you are getting.

Comment: Adding to @PierreLafortune `slope` is also not found

Comment: @amrrs I believe `slope` is created in the `mutate` expression.

Comment: my bad on that 
I will update. the "GM" is a type-o

Comment: `("N0"-"N1")` will not work; you can't subtract strings. What are you trying to calculate?

Comment: @alistaire. I would like to have "N" in the xx. 
in the yy the "value" grouped as "group". 
i.e. how to link the two values of (e.g.) N0 and N2 belonging to group "A" , being the color of the line its slope.

Comment: There are more than two values of N0 and N2 belonging to group "A", though.

Comment: I have now updated the problem.
many thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can split apart the data, and get what you want:

```
#calculate slopes for I and II
dat %>% 
    filter(t != "III") %>%
    group_by(pairs) %>%
    # use diff to calculate slope
    mutate(slope = diff(value)) -> dat12

#calculate slopes for II and III
dat %>% 
    filter(t != "I") %>%
    group_by(pairs) %>%
    # use diff to calculate slope
    mutate(slope = diff(value)) -> dat23

ggplot()+
    geom_line(data = dat12, aes(x = t, y = value, group = pairs, colour = slope > 0,
                                linetype = group))+
    geom_line(data = dat23, aes(x = t, y = value, group = pairs, colour = slope > 0,
                                linetype = group))+
    theme_bw()
```

[image]

Since the data in `dat` came sorted by `t`, I used `diff` to calculate the slope.

Comment: @boucyball
Many thanks for your help, it works perfectly. however my actual problem is a bit more complex. could I kindly ask you to see the following link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39036198/group-factorial-data-with-multiple-factors-error-incompatible-size-0-expe

Many thanks

Comment: I have done it, but since I am new here ... it does not change the publicly displayed post  score

Comment: Is there a shorter way because if i make my database dynamic like with time-series, the I-II and II-III will become to small as it shall have many consecutive line