# Group (factorial) data with multiple factors. error: incompatible size (0), expecting 1 (the group size) or 1

Tags: r, plyr

This post is a following up of [Changing line color in ggplot based on "several factors" slope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39023962/changing-line-color-in-ggplot-based-on-several-factors-slope/39025244#39025244)

I would like to group the data (bellow) by "PQ", however I get the following error:

> "incompatible size (0), expecting 1 (the group size) or 1"

**Data**

```
ID<-c("A_P1","A_P1","A_P1","A_P1","A_P1","A_P2","A_P2","A_P2","A_P2","A_P2","A_P2","B_P1","B_P1","B_P1","B_P1","B_P1","B_P1","B_P1","B_P1","B_P2","B_P2","B_P2","B_P2","B_P2","B_P2","B_P2","B_P2")
Q<-c("C1","C1","C2","C3","C3","C1","C1","C2","C2","C3","C3","Q1","Q1","Q1","Q1","Q3","Q3","Q4","Q4","Q1","Q1","Q1","Q1","Q3","Q3","Q4","Q4")
PQ<-c("A_P1C1","A_P1C1","A_P1C2","A_P1C3","A_P1C3","A_P2C1","A_P2C1","A_P2C2","A_P2C2","A_P2C3","A_P2C3","B_P1Q1","B_P1Q1","B_P1Q1","B_P1Q1","B_P1Q3","B_P1Q3","B_P1Q4","B_P1Q4","B_P2Q1","B_P2Q1","B_P2Q1","B_P2Q1","B_P2Q3","B_P2Q3","B_P2Q4","B_P2Q4")
AS<-c("CF","CF","CF","CF","CF","CTF","CTF","CTF","CTF","CTF","CTF","CTF","CTF","CTF","CTF","CTF","CTF","CTF","CTF","CTF","CTF","CTF","CTF","CTF","CTF","CTF","CTF")
N<-c("N2","N3","N3","N2","N3","N2","N3","N2","N3","N2","N3","N0","N1","N2","N3","N1","N3","N0","N1","N0","N1","N2","N3","N1","N3","N0","N1")
Value<-c(4.7,8.61,8.34,5.89,8.36,1.76,2.4,5.01,2.12,1.88,3.01,2.4,7.28,4.34,5.39,11.61,10.14,3.02,9.45,8.8,7.4,6.93,8.44,7.37,7.81,6.74,8.5)

df<-data.frame(ID=ID,Q=Q,PQ=PQ,AS=AS,N=N,Value=Value)
```

**Code that is delivering the error**

```
#calculate slopes for N0 and N1
    df %>% 
      filter(N=="N0" | N=="N1") %>%
      group_by(PQ) %>%
      # use diff to calculate slope
      mutate(slope = diff(Value)) -> dat01

#calculate slopes for N0 and N2
    df %>% 
      filter(N=="N0" | N=="N2") %>%
      group_by(PQ) %>%
      # use diff to calculate slope
      mutate(slope = diff(Value)) -> dat02
```

Additionally, I would like to calculate the slope of the the remaining "PQ" factors (when existent), i.e. N0-N3;N1-N2 ... and so on

Comment: The `diff` returns one element less than the original dataset, so you need `c(0, diff(value))` to correct that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is due to the difference in length from the output of `diff` with respect to the original dataset.  It returns one element less than the original data.  So appending a 0 or NA will solve the issue

```
df %>% 
   filter(N=="N0" | N=="N1") %>%
   group_by(PQ) %>% 
   mutate(slope = c(0, diff(Value)))
```

To make it compact, instead of `==`, we can use `%in%` when there are multiple elements

```
df %>%
   filter(N %in%  paste0("N", 0:1)) %>%
   group_by(PQ) %>%
   mutate(slope = c(0, diff(Value)))
```

---

Regarding the second issue, about doing this for all the combinations in 'N', use the `combn` on the `unique` elements of 'N', `filter` the 'N' based on the combination values, after grouping by 'PQ', calculate the `diff` of 'Value'.  The output will be a `list` as we specified `simplify = FALSE`.

```
combn(as.character(unique(df$N)),2, FUN = function(x) df %>% 
            filter(N %in% x) %>% 
            group_by(PQ) %>%
            mutate(slope = c(0, diff(Value))), simplify = FALSE )
```

Comment: Hi,
I did but since I have not "15 reputation", it does not change the status :(
sorry