# Line color and width by slope in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

This is relates very closely to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34113989/changing-line-color-in-ggplot-based-on-slope), as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39023962/changing-line-color-in-ggplot-based-on-several-factors-slope/39025244), answers to which I don't understand, at least in this context. I would like to make the difference between increasing and decreasing scores (e.g. repeated psychological measurements from T1 to T2) prominent by placing a heatmap-style gradient on lines based on their slopes. In other words, I'd like to use e.g. [Viridis](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/viridis/vignettes/intro-to-viridis.html)'s inferno-scale, so that the lines which decrease most sharply tend towards darkness and those which increase most sharply tend towards light.

Many thanks for any ideas!

```
data <- data.frame(id = 1:500, 
                               Intrinsic_01_T1 = sample(1:5, 500, replace = TRUE), 
                               Intrinsic_02_T1 = sample(1:5, 500, replace = TRUE), 
                               Intrinsic_03_T1 = sample(1:5, 500, replace = TRUE), 
                               Intrinsic_01_T2 = sample(1:5, 500, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3)), 
                               Intrinsic_02_T2 = sample(1:5, 500, replace = TRUE), 
                               Intrinsic_03_T2 = sample(1:5, 500, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1)))

pd <- position_dodge(0.4)

data %>% 
  tidyr::gather(variable, value, -id) %>% 
  tidyr::separate(variable, c("item", "time"), sep = "_T") %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(value = jitter(value, amount = 0.1)) %>% # Y-axis jitter to make points more readable
ggplot(aes(x = time, y = value, group = id)) +
  geom_point(size = 1, alpha = .2, position = pd) +
  geom_line(alpha = .2, position = pd) +
  ggtitle('Multiple indicator LCS model') + 
  ylab('Intrinsic motivation scores') +
  xlab('Time points') + 
  facet_wrap("item")
```

[image: The resulting figure]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to calculate your slope for each line before plotting. To do this you can `group by` the time and item and then calculate the slope for each line.

```
data %>% 
  tidyr::gather(variable, value, -id) %>% 
  tidyr::separate(variable, c("item", "time"), sep = "_T") %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(value = jitter(value, amount = 0.1)) %>%  # Y-axis jitter to make points more readable
  group_by(id,item) %>% 
  mutate(slope = (value[time==2] - value[time==1])/(2-1)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = time, y = value, group = id)) +
  geom_point(size = 1, alpha = .2, position = pd) +
  geom_line(alpha = .2, position = pd, aes(color = slope)) +
  scale_color_viridis_c(option = "inferno")+
   ggtitle('Multiple indicator LCS model') + 
  ylab('Intrinsic motivation scores') +
  xlab('Time points') + 
  facet_wrap("item")
```

Resulting in:

[image]

Comment: Holy hell, this is amazing - many thanks! One question out of curiosity; why is the difference between values divided by "(2-1)"?

Comment: Nothing. It's just in case you end up running it on time points where t2-t1 isn`t 1

Comment: [deleted a follow-up question I ended up figuring out]