# How to manually pick colors of geom_line() in ggplot2 based on the slope's sign? R

Tags: ggplot2

(apologies in advance, I don't know how to make the output show up here...)

I'm trying to create a line graph where the lines are colored red if positive slope or green if negative slope. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34113989/changing-line-color-in-ggplot-based-on-slope/34114560) which was very helpful, but I'd like to change the colors manually to red and green.

This is as far as I got, using a different way to find slope because it made more sense to my brain.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

data <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,4,5),
                 y=c(1,3,2,6,5))

Slope = function(x) {
    TempDF = data.frame(x, z=1:ncol(data))
    lm(x ~ z, data=TempDF)$coefficients[2]
}

TData = as.data.frame(t(data))
data$slope = sapply(TData, Slope)
data$slope <- round(data$slope, digits=3)

data <- data %>%
  mutate(
    sign = case_when(
    slope == 0 ~ "zero",
    slope > 0 ~ "pos",
    slope < 0 ~ "neg"))  

head(data)

cols <- c("zero" = "grey", "pos" = "red", "neg" = "green")

g <- ggplot(data, aes(x=x,y=y, colour=sign)) +
  geom_point(aes(color=NULL)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_colour_manual(values = cols)
g
```

However, it produces this, which is obviously not what I want...

[bad graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2f6uI.png)